# offline lightweight html viewer

Tags: linux, html, offline

I am using lots of offline documentation in html. I would like to browse and view it (GUI) *offline* without having to use a full-blown browser like Firefox, Chromium etc, because:

- I wish to ensure that no communication is being sent to tracking agents (Google, fex, is *extremely* adept at extracting data, even if you arm yourself with the elite array of privacy plugins)
- Mainstream browsers are very resource hungry, and are currently causing freezes on my setup.

It would have to:

- support moderately modern HTML and CSS.
- support simple javascript (I am not sure if one can do 100% without)
- be open source
- compile and run on linux (x64)
- (preferably) not employ any networking libraries

Are there any existing software alternatives for this?

Comment: Why lightweight? Why an extra app? Why not just save the web page (which you have to do anyway), and view it in your normal browser?  Do you have requirements as to what should happen when unavailable links are clicked? Anything else? You don’t give much of a description, which makes it difficult to help you. Please read [ask]. Welcome aboard and please don’t take that the wrong way, but the more details you give us, there better we can help you – and we do want to. For instance, which operating system do you want this for? Must it be free, or do you have a budget in mind? Etc, etc, etc

Comment: http://html-reader-v.software.informer.com/ is described as "Small, powerful off-line HTML Viewer that runs off a floppy and requires no winsock.dll." Try that & tell us what you don't like

Comment: Sorry I will clarify